# Pass IIS API service credentials to ftp server in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, credentials

I have created an application service run on my IIS server.

That is based on REST (web server).

The service want to access a remote FTP server.

The service is related to application pool, with the "localservice" user.

I want to access the FTP server with no anonymous user available to connect.

How can I connect with c# to the specific ftp server using same credentials as the current running user (local service) without need to save the user and password in a configuration file?

What is the best practice for doing so?

Thanks.

Comment: See Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: I don't understand how that solve. The Ftp is on remoter server. What can I write in C#, and how can I configure the Ftp site in order to enable users/roles, and in other server that uses the FTP, (i.e rest api on web server) the account is hidden, and not in any configuration file (i.e a localservice from the application pool). Whatvis the best practice to not use password in configuration file, but success access to remote ftp. Need a c# code, please.

Comment: Is remote machine in same network as client using same credentials?

Comment: Yes. it on the same network, but may change in future  (it there any solution if not? If yes - what is the solution?

Comment: LocalService presents anonymous credentials to other servers; that’s one of the reasons to prefer it. Standard FTP traffic is insecure, so you don’t want to be including privileged credentials along with that on a network anyway. Just use configuration in your API.

Comment: Do you mean the user + password in the configuration file? Can I solve the solution without any user+password in configuration? What to do?

Comment: That is why I provided the link to Roles so you can set the Role properly.  The Role takes the client credential  at server and passes it to FTP connection.